# Need to search the recently modified file in SSIS and rename it

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, msbi

I have a requirement of finding the **recently modified/created file** from a directory and rename it to a standard name **run that file** and then rename it back to previous name. How can this be achieved?

Steps needed to be achieved:

1. finding the recently modified/created file
2. rename that file to a standard name.
3. run that file
4. rename it back to previous name.

I used a script task to find the recent file, but i could not move forward. I tried many things. Any solution on how to implement this?

I used this blog to find the **recently modified/created file** - https://www.techbrothersit.com/2013/12/ssis-how-to-get-most-recent-file-from.html

Comment: You can save the list of obtained files in an object variable. Continue using a foreach loop.

Comment: The list of files are dynamic. So it changes from time to time. And also I need the recently modified file.